# Remove CSS class from previous div tags

Tags: jquery, css

I want to remove a CSS class from previous elements. So its like number of div tags diplay on first page and when I scroll further second page div tags displayed. So when I am on second page I want to remove active class from all div tags from previous page.

```
<div id="container">
 <div class="campaign-line active">something</div>
 <div class="campaign-line active">something</div>
 <div class="campaign-line active">something</div>
 <div class="campaign-line active">something</div>
 <div class="campaign-line active">something</div>

 <div class="campaign-line active">something</div>
</div>
```

What I have tried is :

```
$("#container").children(".campaign-line:first").removeClass("active");
```

But it's removing active class from first div tag.

Comment: `previous` relating to what?

Comment: How do you execute this code, using a handler? Do you want more than one active div or just one? Your question is not clear IMO

Comment: Yes your code is working correct. :first will select the first child.

Comment: @ArturUdod there is a pagination on page so when I scroll my page to the end it displays content fetched for second page so I want to remove active class from previous div tags and want to add active to second page div tag

Comment: @roasted there is a pagination on page so when I scroll my page to the end it displays content fetched for second page so I want to remove active class from previous div tags and want to add active to second page div tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ID Value is wrong and you should not use `.campaign-line:first` . Try the below and hope you add the `previous` class for identification.

```
$("#container").children(".campaign-line").removeClass("active");
```

Note: Add the `:first` in the right markup

Comment: omg, this will just remove class from first `div`, obviously OP just made a typo in question.

Comment: I agree. i just correct his mistake, he need to add :first in the right markup, since second page markup is not mentioned

Comment: @Venkat, that makes sense, if you edit your question I will remove the downvote.

Comment: @Artur: I added the Note. check out now